# File naming when working with paths

Tags: python

So I have the following code and I'm trying to export a csv and immediately open it in Python.

```
# define weekly pull code
def GT_Weekly_Run(keys):
    # connect to Google
    connector = pyGTrends(google_username, google_password)
    # make request
    connector.request_report(keys, geo="US")
    # wait a random amount of time between requests to avoid bot detection
    time.sleep(randint(5, 10))
    # download file
    connector.save_csv(path, '_' + "GT_Weekly" + '_' + keys)

    name = path, '_' + "GT_Weekly" + '_' + keys
    with open(name + '.csv', 'rt') as csvfile:    
        csvReader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        data = []

        data = [row for row in csvReader if row and row[0].startswith("20")]
        week_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

        cols = ["Date", "Trend"]    
        week_df.columns = [cols]
```

The problem is that I'm not able to match the save as file name with the open file name. Have tried a number of things but keep getting errors regarding

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'GT_Weekly_football.csv'

TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple
```

Is there anything that looks off. I just need to go from saving the file as X and using that same name (X) to import it back in.

Thanks!

Comment: `name = path, '_' + "GT_Weekly" + '_' + keys` makes `name` a two element tuple. But in the `open` call you try to concatenate a string to that tuple with `name + '.csv'`. You probably meant to do `name = path + '_' + "GT_Weekly" + '_' + keys`. However, as Martin points out it's better to use the `os.path.join` function when building file paths.

Comment: Key's is just a single string, "baseball"

Comment: The error messages are telling you the problems: it can't find a file named GT_Weekly_football.csv (relative path) and you can't concatenate a `tuple` and a `str` (done by `+`).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you create a variable to hold the filename. That way, the same name will be used both for creation and loading back.

```
import os 

# define weekly pull code
def GT_Weekly_Run(keys):
    # connect to Google
    connector = pyGTrends(google_username, google_password)
    # make request
    connector.request_report(keys, geo="US")
    # wait a random amount of time between requests to avoid bot detection
    time.sleep(randint(5, 10))

    # download file

    filename = "_GT_Weekly_" + keys
    connector.save_csv(path, filename)

    with open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'rt') as csvfile:    
        csvReader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        data = []

        data = [row for row in csvReader if row and row[0].startswith("20")]
        week_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

        cols = ["Date", "Trend"]    
        week_df.columns = [cols]
```

It is safer to make use of Python's `os.path.join` function to create your full file names.

Also take a look at the `keys` parameter you are passing to `GT_Weekly_Run`, it should just be a simple string.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Did get the following error: TypeError: save_csv() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Comment: Try now, your `save_csv` function obviously needs the path seperately.

Comment: Yeah, it's a method within some broader class.  Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-34-80e36f2cf046>", line 2, in <module>
    GT_Weekly_Run("football")

  File "<ipython-input-32-9c83ea4a93f3>", line 14, in GT_Weekly_Run
    with open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'rt') as csvfile:

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Forecast_Process\\_GT_Weekly_football'

Comment: Can you change `path` to be a full path?

Comment: I have it set to the location where my subdirectory is: path = 'S:\\Root\\Legacy\\SAS_Work\\Clients\\OfficeDepot\\Forecast_Process'

Comment: Can you add a `print path` just before the `save_csv`? The error message does not show the whole path?  Perhaps pass it as an argument to the function.